# Recursion Function to search

Tags: javascript, recursion

How would I go about creating a recursive function that can search through a list for a node where x = 10?

I do not have any javascript experience so I am not sure where to start so would appreciate and input

I have come across the following code and tried to adapt it but I am not sure if I am on the right track:

```
function search(_for, _in) {
    var r;
    for (var p in _in) {
        if ( p === 10 ) {
            return _in[p];
        }
        if ( typeof _in[p] === 'object' ) {
            if ( (r = search(_for, _in[p])) !== null ) {
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var finder = function(needle, haystack) {
    if (haystack.length == 0) 
        return false

    if (haystack[0] == needle)
        return true

    return finder(pin, haystack.slice(1))
}
```

Or

```
var finder = function(pin, haystack) {
    return (haystack[0] == pin) || (haystack.length != 0) && finder(pin, haystack.slice(1)) 
}
```

Recursion FTW

Comment: Thank @Simon but if I may ask how does it know that X should be 10 if there is no 10 in the code? Sorry for asking, I am just trying to understand it as I go along

Comment: `finder(needle, haystack)` searches for needle in haystack, so you can just use `finder(10, haystack)` unless I misunderstood your question